# How do I solve "Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Setting unknown property: craft\fields\Assets::branchLimit"

Tags: craft3, craft-features

First of all I am new in CraftCms.
I am trying to run the project local which I cloned, so I have a database which I must import to this project. now its giving this error when I finish importing the database
 `"Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException Setting unknown property: craft\fields\Assets::branchLimit"`
any help will do.

for more detailed stack trace

```
yii\base\UnknownPropertyException: Setting unknown property: craft\fields\Assets::branchLimit in /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Component.php:209
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(558): yii\base\Component->__set('branchLimit', NULL)
#1 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(107): yii\BaseYii::configure(Object(craft\fields\Assets), Array)
#2 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/base/Model.php(78): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#3 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/BaseRelationField.php(252): craft\base\Model->__construct(Array)
#4 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/fields/Assets.php(220): craft\fields\BaseRelationField->__construct(Array)
#5 [internal function]: craft\fields\Assets->__construct(Array)
#6 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(419): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#7 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\fields\\As...', Array, Array)
#8 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\fields\\As...', Array, Array)
#9 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php(53): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#10 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/helpers/Component.php(121): Craft::createObject(Array)
#11 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(593): craft\helpers\Component::createComponent(Array, 'craft\\base\\Fiel...')
#12 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(618): craft\services\Fields->createField(Array)
#13 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/services/Fields.php(647): craft\services\Fields->_fields(NULL)
#14 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1908): craft\services\Fields->getAllFields()
#15 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1277): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->customFields()
#16 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/QueryBuilder.php(227): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->prepare(Object(craft\db\mysql\QueryBuilder))
#17 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(157): yii\db\QueryBuilder->build(Object(craft\elements\db\UserQuery))
#18 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Query.php(287): yii\db\Query->createCommand(Object(craft\db\Connection))
#19 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/db/Query.php(180): yii\db\Query->one(NULL)
#20 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/db/ElementQuery.php(1440): craft\db\Query->one(NULL)
#21 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/elements/User.php(535): craft\elements\db\ElementQuery->one()
#22 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php(697): craft\elements\User::findIdentity(1)
#23 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/User.php(500): yii\web\User->renewAuthStatus()
#24 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php(198): craft\web\User->renewAuthStatus()
#25 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(423): yii\web\User->getIdentity()
#26 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php(107): craft\web\Application->debugBootstrap()
#27 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/BaseObject.php(109): craft\web\Application->init()
#28 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(204): yii\base\BaseObject->__construct(Array)
#29 [internal function]: yii\base\Application->__construct(Array)
#30 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(419): ReflectionClass->newInstanceArgs(Array)
#31 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php(170): yii\di\Container->build('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#32 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/BaseYii.php(365): yii\di\Container->get('craft\\web\\Appli...', Array, Array)
#33 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/Craft.php(53): yii\BaseYii::createObject(Array, Array)
#34 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/bootstrap.php(239): Craft::createObject(Array)
#35 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/vendor/craftcms/cms/bootstrap/web.php(40): require('/Users/blessing...')
#36 /Users/blessingjackson/Documents/northernleaf2023/web/index.php(21): require('/Users/blessing...')
#37 {main}
```

This is only happening when I import the data base.

Comment: Please make an effort to properly formulate and format your question.

Comment: @MoritzLost is it much better or I still need to do more formatting?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you're trying to import a database dump that was created on a different version of Craft than the one you're running locally. The `Assets::branchLimit` property was [introduced in Craft 4.4](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v4/craft-fields-baserelationfield.html#public-properties), so it's a quite recent addition.

Make sure that you're importing the database with the same version that was used to create the database dump. If you want to update to a newer version, first make sure your local installation is running the same version as the database version, then do the update once you have successfully imported the database and the site is working locally.

If your local installation is running Craft <4.4, update to 4.4.x first and then try to import the dump.